# Glob without permission to delete?

Tags: python, unix, jupyter, file-permissions, glob

On a unix system, is it possible to create directory permissions such that globing the list of files is possible, but deleting them is not?

It seems like this may not be possible, which I'm a bit surprised by.

I'd like to be able to `glob('/directory/*')` in a Jupyter notebook cell to see directory contents, without being able to delete any of the files.

Comment: `r-x` looks about right

Comment: I did `a-wx+r` but am unable to `ls` the contents of a directory (it contains symlinks)

Comment: sorry, I was not clear. I meant, you need read and execute (cd and list for directories), but not write. That will translate into `chmod 555 /directory` (I wasn't sure what accounts it will be executed and read from)

Comment: but doesn't execute permissions also give permissions to delete the files?

Comment: no, `x` on directories only allows to cd